# Subversion - Set default commit hook?

Tags: scripting, svn

Is there anyway to set a custom commit hook to be a "default" hook when repositories are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the nine standard hooks installed into a new repository by the 'svnadmin create /path/to/repo' command (start-commit, pre/post-commit, pre/post-revprop-change, pre/post-lock, and pre/post-unlock), I know of no way to have additional hooks automatically included as a "default" hook for all newly created repositories.

I suppose you could build a wrapper shell script for creating new repositories that calls the svnadmin create command with a variable set for the repository path followed by a copying of the custom commit hook into the path/to/repo/hooks folder and use that for all new repositories.

Lastly, because you mention that this custom hook in particular is a commit hook, I should repeat the warning given by [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) when discussing [hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) (emphasis mine):

> While hook scripts can do almost
>   anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show
>   restraint: **do not modify a commit
>   transaction using hook scripts**.
>   While it might be tempting to use hook
>   scripts to automatically correct
>   errors, shortcomings, or policy
>   violations present in the files being
>   committed, doing so can cause
>   problems. Subversion keeps client-side
>   caches of certain bits of repository
>   data, and if you change a commit
>   transaction in this way, those caches
>   become indetectably stale. This
>   inconsistency can lead to surprising
>   and unexpected behavior. Instead of
>   modifying the transaction, you should
>   simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit
>   if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users
>   will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits